# Adding a character beginning and end of each line to text file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a 'text.txt' file This text file has 1000 different line and I want to add a beginnig of each line " and also add end of each line ",

> Block quote

Please help me

Comment: Can you explain bit more with code what are you trying to say? Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @v8-E my question is clear I have code in PHP language

Comment: so edit this question,add that code here and explain what problem you are facing

Comment: @v8-E thx a lot bro I do not want to answer my question

Answer (score 2):

You can use file to open a file and make it an array per line.
Then loop it and add the `"` and save it again.

```
$arr = file("text.txt");
foreach($arr as &$line){
    $line = '"' . $line . '"';
}
unset($line); //just in case and a good thing to remember in other projects
file_put_contents("text.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, $arr)); // write file with new line separating the array items.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

   $str = 'sometext';

   echo '"'.$str.'"';

   //expected output
   "sometext"
?>
```

You can concat them using [period] operator. [How to concat string in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: I have a text file not string

Answer (score 0):

```
//open file
    $myfile = fopen("logs.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $txt = "user id date";
    $txt = "'".$txt."'"; //add concatenation here

//write
    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: bro I have a text file with a 1000 line different text

Comment: That was not mentioned in the question. Edit your question to include all facts about the file, and what attempts you have done to solve your problem

Comment: This is adding `'` while OP wants/needs `"`